# Как определить с помощью if, является ли число целым либо с плавающей точкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите пожалуйста (с примером)

Comment: isinstance(число, float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создание условий с проверкой типа float:

```
type(2.3) == float
# True

type(2.3) == float or type(2.3) == decimal.Decimal
# True

type(2.3) is float
# True

type(2.3) is not int
# True

isinstance(2.3, float)
# True

isinstance(2.3, (float, decimal.Decimal))
# True

2.3.is_integer()
# False
```

Comment: `is` вместо `==` более питоничиское. Иначе красивый ответ.